# Need help creating JSON date using C#

Tags: c#, json

Here's how part of my JSON should look like:

```
"CreateDate":"\/Date(1062522780000-0500)\/"
```

This is my C# where I'm trying to create it:

```
"\"CreateDate\": \"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "\"," +
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: It seems like you did it...  What do you need help with?

Comment: Why do you need your json to look like that? That's the way asp.net services render DateTime fields, but unless you have a good reason to use that format you could use any other.

Answer (score 3):

To work with json use a Json parser like [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/), [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
string json=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new {CreateDate=DateTime.Now });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use  the `JavaScriptSerializer` or `DataContractJsonSerializer` for serializing the object to json, the date will look like that.

If you are using MVC, you can just do

```
return JSon( yourObj );
```

from the action method.